# 1000 items, 1000 nodes, 3 items per node, best replication scheme to minimize data loss as nodes fail?

Tags: algorithm

I was wondering what would be the right answer for [Question 2-44](http://www2.algorithm.cs.sunysb.edu:8080/mediawiki/index.php/Algo-analysis-TADM2E) in Skiena's *Algorithm Design Manual* (2nd ed.)

The question is the following:

> We have 1,000 data items to store on 1,000 nodes. Each node can store
>   copies of exactly three different items. Propose a replication scheme
>   to minimize data loss as nodes fail. What is the expected number of
>   data entries that get lost when three random nodes fail?

I was thinking about node n having data item from n, n+1 & n+2.

So if 3 consecutive nodes are lost then we lose 1 item.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: You should really edit enough of the problem description into your question that the question is still meaningful when/if the link dies.

Comment: Added the problem description

Comment: Hmm, I understood it as there are 1000 data items (label them d1, d2... d1000) and 1000 nodes (n1, n2...n1000).

d1 to d1000 are unique(such as unique computer files) and we can copy each of them exactly 3 times to each node. 

For instance: n1 can contain (d1, d2, d3), n2 (d4, d5, d6) ... n333(d997, d998, d999), n334(d1000, d1, d2) and we repeat.

So we need at least 334 nodes to save the original data, then another 334 to save the first copy and finally another 334, but we can't because: 334 + 334 + `332` = 1000

Comment: And your thinking of having n node contain data items n, n+1, n+2, so that one node has exactly three items, E.x: n = 10, stored data: 10, 11, 12, but what if n = 1000, then you have: 1001, 1002, 1003, it just overflowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach you propose is not bad but also take a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAID). The ideas used in RAID may give you some ideas. For instance if you have 2 data items, than having storage for 3 items you can recover any of them if the other fails. The idea is quite simple - you store the items in 2 nodes and the xor of their bits in the third item. I believe if you utilize this idea you will be able to have more then 3 backups of a single data item(i.e. more then 3 nodes have to fail in order to loose the information).

Answer (score 3):

I thought of methods like RAID levels but Skiena says "each node can store copies of exactly three different items." Even though XOR'red bit patterns of two separate data can be stored in the same amount of space, I did not think that it was something the problem was looking for.

So, I started with what the OP thought of: Store the three copies of each data to its next two neighbors in a striped fashion. For example, the following is for when N==6 and the data are the integers from 0 to 5 (4 and 5 wrap around and use the nodes 0 and 1):

```
nodes:    0 1 2 3 4 5
          ===========
copy 0 -> 0 1 2 3 4 5 
copy 1 -> 5 0 1 2 3 4 
copy 2 -> 4 5 0 1 2 3
```

Of all the 20 combinations of three-node failures, there are six that lose exactly one piece of data. For example; when nodes 1, 2, and 3 fail, the data 1 gets lost:

```
===========
0 X X X 4 5 
5 X X X 3 4 
4 X X X 2 3
```

Similar for each other data, making 6 of the 20 combinations lose data. Since Skiena does not describe what "data loss" means for the application: Does the loss of a single data point mean that the entire collection is wasted, or losing a single data point is acceptable and is better than losing two?

If the loss of even a single data point means that the entire collection is wasted, then we can do better. Three times better! :)

Instead of distributing the copies of data to the right-hand nodes in a striped fashion, define groups of three nodes that share data. For example, let 0, 1, and 2 share their data and 3, 4, and 5 share their data:

```
nodes:    0 1 2 3 4 5
          ===========
copy 0 -> 0 1 2 3 4 5
copy 1 -> 2 0 1 5 3 4
copy 2 -> 1 2 0 4 5 3
```

This time, there are only 2 of the 20 combinations produce data loss ever. Data 0, 1, and 2 are lost together when nodes 0, 1, and 2 fail:

```
===========
x x x 3 4 5
x x x 5 3 4
x x x 4 5 3
```

And data 3, 4, and 5 are lost together when nodes 3, 4, and 5 fail:

```
===========
0 1 2 x x x
2 0 1 x x x
1 2 0 x x x
```

That amounts to just 2 of the 20 combinations of three-node failures. When the same nodes share same data, it effectively merges data losses into fewer number of combinations.

Ali

Comment: "Of all the 20 combinations of three-node failures" - aren't there actually just 10 unique combinations?

Comment: But doesn't this increase the chances of 3 nodes failing equals 3 data items lost? In the previous scheme you only ever lost a single data item per 3 node failure event.

Answer (score 1):

Let,

```
 D = {1,...,d_i,...,d} denote the data items and d_i a given data element
 N = {1,...,n_k,...,n} denote the storage cluster and n_k a given storage node. 
 We say d_i is stored by n_k, loosely denoted by d_i \in n_k.
```

My replication model has the following assumptions:

1- Every data item must be stored at least in one given node during initialization. I.e.:

```
   Exist at least one 1 <= k <=n s.t. P(d_i \in n_k) = 1.
```

2- From (1), at initialization time, the probability of d_i to be in a given node is at least 1/n. I.e.:

```
   For any data item 1 <= i <= d and a random node n, P(d_i \in n) >= 1/n.
```

Given the problem statement, by design, we want to have this distribution uniform across the data set.

3- Lastly, by design, the probability of a data item d_i to be in a given node n should be independent between data items. I.e.:

```
  P(d_i \in n | d_j \in n) = P(d_i \in n)
```

This is because we don't assume the probability of node failure is independent between adjacent nodes (e.g.: in datacenters adjacent nodes be sharing the same network switch, etc).

From these assumptions, I proposed the following replication model (for the problem instance where d = n and each node stores exactly 3 distinct data items).

(1) Perform a random permutation of data set.
(2) Using a sliding window of length 3 and stride 1, rotate over the shuffled data set and map the data items to each node.

```
E.g.:
D = {A,B,C,D}
N = {1,2,3,4}

(1) {C, B, A, D}
(2) 1 -> {C, B, A}, 2 -> {B, A, D}, 3-> {A, D, C}, 4-> {D, C, B}
```

the random shuffling will ensure independent (3) and uniform distribution (2). While the sliding window of stride 1 guarantees (1).

Let's denote, the sliding window of a given node n_k as the ordered set w_k = {w_k1, w_k2, w_k3}. n_k is said to be the master node for w_k1 (first element of w_k). Any other node n_j containing w_k1 is a replica node. N.B.: the proposed replication model guarantees only one master node for any d_i, while the number of replica nodes depends on the window length.

In the example above: n_1 is the master node for C and n_3 and n_4 replica nodes.

Back to the original problem, given this schema, we can state the probability of data loss is the lost of the master node and all replicas for a given data item.

P(d_i is lost) = P(master node for d_i fails and replica 1 fails and replica 2 fails).

without formal proof, an unbiased random permutation in step (1) above would result

P(d_i is lost) = P(master node for d_i fails) * P(replica 1 fails) * P(replica 2 fails).

again, the random permutation is a heuristic to abstract the joint distribution for nodes failure.

From assumptions (2) and (3), P(d_i is lost) = c, for any d_i, at initialization time.

That said for d = n = 1000 and replication factor of 3 (i.e.: window length equals 3).

P(d_i is lost) = 1/1000 * 1/999 * 1/998 ~ 10^-9

Comment: You overlooked the fact that there are 1000 candidates for `d_i`. Hence, you should multiply your final figure by a factor of 1000 to get: `P(d_i is lost) = 1/999 * 1/998 ~ 10^-6`. In other words, the choice of the first element doesn't matter, as long as the second and third are chosen accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach seems essentially correct but can benefit from a failover strategy. Notice that Prof. Skiena has asked "to minimize data loss as nodes fail" which suggests that failing nodes will be a common occurrence.

You may want to have a look at [consistent hashing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_hashing).

Also, there is a [great post](http://www.redditblog.com/2010/03/and-fun-weekend-was-had-by-all.html) by reddit engineers about the perils of not using consistent hashing (instead using a fixed MOD hashing).